# Loop a promise returned by redis on nodejs

Tags: node.js, loops, redis, promise, sortedset

I'm trying to use a promise in a for loop.
I feel like it's time for me to use Promise.all for the first time but I don't seem to be able to make it work.

Here is what I have so far:

```
redis.keys('en:230:*')
    .then(function(result) {
        // result = ['en:230.1', 'en:230.2', 'en:230.5', 'en:230.10', 'en:230.3', 'en:230.75']
        for (var k = 0; k < result.length; ++k) {
            redis.zcount(result[k])
                .then(function(r) {
                    console.log(r);
                })
        }
    })
```

My goal is to count all "result" sorted sets and put every result in another sorted set called en:230:top
This would contain the count result for score and 1,2,5,10,3,75 for value.

Currently, I'm only trying to loop throught all "result" and count.

Anyone can give me a hand ?

Edit:

What I have understood from Promise.all is the following.
Does something like this should work ?

```
var array = [];
redis.keys('en:230:*')
    .then(function(result) {
        // result = ['en:230.1', 'en:230.2', 'en:230.5', 'en:230.10', 'en:230.3', 'en:230.75']
        for (var k = 0; k < result.length; ++k) {
            array.push(redis.zcount(result[k]));
        }
        return Promise.all(array);
    })
    .then(function(r) {
        console.log(r);
    })
```

Comment: Sounds like you know the solution already: `Promise.all`. What's the problem?

Comment: Yes, "something like this" should work (although I'd recommend to put the `var array = []` inside the callback). Haven't you tried it out?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works just fine actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Promise.all](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html):

```
redis.keys('en:230:*')
    .then(function (results) {

        // collect individual promises in an array
        var queries = results.map(function (r) {
            return redis.zcount(r);
        });

        // return a promise that resolves when all of query promises resolve
        return Promise.all(queries);
    })
    .then(function (counts) {
        // do something with counts
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        // oops
    });
```

Comment: It works fine, thanks a lot. I just add to remove the A in return Promise.All(queries); and put an small a. Thanks!